# Symfony Model abstraction (to SQL or NoSQL)

Tags: php, sql, symfony, nosql, abstraction

I am starting a new (and first) project with Symfony2, but I didn't choise Database engine yet. And it could be MySQL or NoSQL engines like MongoDB or others, or also it could be changed along the proyect cycle. 
So, I would like to start working without limitation of choising Doctrine, Doctrine for Mongo or others. And allowing posibility of changing only model layer without big impact on controllers, and classes.

Recomendations? Comments? Best Practices?

Comment: Sounds like analysis paralysis. I'd recommend you get started with *something*, *anything*. If you're not very experienced, go with the more stable, well documented and wide spread technology (MySQL). Unless you have specific requirements for your database engine that warrant a careful consideration between the two technologies right now, both will probably work equally fine.

Comment: That is the true deceze, it was analysis paralysis! Looking for motivation I found this excellent article where write about it http://postmasculine.com/analysis-paralysis.

So.. Stop thinking and just do it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this](http://www.phpdevtips.com/2011/08/data-encryption-using-aes_encrypt/) tutorial will help you to get some knowledge. However try to learn the main concepts before doing any major development.